# I have two MySQL data base mysql

Tags: mysql, joomla, replicate

I have two MySQL databases that replicate such as master master:

- mysql1 192.168.10.244
- mysql2 192.168.10.245

My Joomla is on IP 192.168.10.243.

What can I do connected Joomla to the database?

OS: CentOS 6.8

Answer (score 0):

In a Joomla environment, you should connect to the master as Joomla websites write frequently to the database. The slave will do the replication automatically.

If you want to go the extra mile, you should connect to an interface (the same way as you connect to any MySQL database), which then routes the traffic either to your master or your slave. Typically, the networking people are responsible for creating such interface.